# Can a table have multiple records of a single column in a single row?

Tags: mysql, row

There is a table 'items' with columns : item_name, i_code, items_left & price. It stores all the items that a shop sells. There is another table 'customers'. It stores record of all the customers who visited the shop. I want to keep record of all the items that a particular customer bought. I want to create a column 'items_bought' in 'customers' table, that will store item codes of all the items a particular customer bought. But having more than one item code for a particular customer row is impossible. Please help me have multiple records of items_bought in a single row of customers.

Comment: save all your data in that column separated by commas. Then wonder why all of your queries have to use find_in_set and group_concat to get to your data. You will be miserable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, yes you can have multiple values in a single field for each row. A comma separated field could be a solution.

If you are using a relational database, your life will be easier if you create a new table, let's say `items_bought`, that will hold the relation between customer and item bought.

For example

```
create table `items_bought`
 (id int not null primary key,
 item_id int not null,
 customer_id int not null)
```

Each field `item_id` and `customer_id` will have a foreign key to `items.id` and `customers.id` table fields respectively.

This way you don't need to manage strings and parse comma separated values. You can simply query your tables like:

```
select * 
from `items` i 
 inner join `items_bought` ib on i.id = ib.item_id
 inner join `customers` c on ib.customer_id = c.id
```

The above query will return all customer and item information of customers that have bought at least one item.

Answer (score 1):

this is possible,but not suggested,
you can save your item code in customer table with 
 or with comma or environment.newline

but it has not any use except display

my suggested solution is create a new table CustomerItem, having CustomerId,ItemId and other common attribute, that should b between Customer& Item like purchase rate, time of purchase etc(you cannot do it in above method)

Comment: and because we know he will save with commas, he can also save his quantities all in one column separated by commas, and same for price column